# gradle - system.out.println debugs

Tags: gradle, build

I have below task in gradle build file and the highlighted class is having some system.out.println statements, but i dont see the debugs in console where gradle build is fired.
where can i find the system.out.println debugs when gradle build is fired?

i tried gradle build with --debug, --quiet, --stacktrace but nothing worked.

```
task compileJasperJava {
    def jasperSourceDir = file('src/main/jasperreports')
    def jasperTargetDir = file('build/classes/main/jasperreports')
    
    ant {
          taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: '**net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask**', classpath: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
        jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir:jasperTargetDir) {
            //classpath(path: FINRPT/jasper)
            //include(name: '**/*.jrxml')
            include(name:'**/*.jrxml')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

system.out comes in gradle console with debug mode like below.

2020-10-28T04:46:35.634+0000 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:jrc] Error compiling report design : compileux/customjrxml/src/main/jasperreports/UBBDFail.jrxml